# The spaceBetween function isn't working for the swiper

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have some issues with my horizontal swiper. I'm trying to code a horizontal swiper, filled with images with variable widths but the same height with a fixed spaceBetween. Somehow it doesn't work and I can't find the mistake.

```
  That's the code so far.
```

```
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide"> 
                <div class="video-responsive_slider">
                    <video class="video-responsive-item_slider" src="links/Branding_Theater_Marie/Marie_Website_Rendering_Mobile_3000px.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide"> 
                <img class="lazyload bild" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_02_3000px.jpg 3000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_02_2000px.jpg 2000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_02_1000px.jpg 1000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_02_600px.jpg 600w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_02_400px.jpg 400w,"
                >
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide"> 
                <img class="lazyload bild" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_13_3000px.jpg 3000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_13_2000px.jpg 2000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_13_1000px.jpg 1000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_13_600px.jpg 600w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_13_400px.jpg 400w,"
                >
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide"> 
                <img class="lazyload bild" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_06_3000px.jpg 3000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_06_2000px.jpg 2000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_06_1000px.jpg 1000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_06_600px.jpg 600w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_06_400px.jpg 400w,"
                >
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide"> 
                <img class="lazyload bild" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_05_3000px.jpg 3000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_05_2000px.jpg 2000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_05_1000px.jpg 1000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_05_600px.jpg 600w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_05_400px.jpg 400w,"
                >
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide"> 
                <img class="lazyload bild" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_14_3000px.jpg 3000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_14_2000px.jpg 2000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_14_1000px.jpg 1000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_14_600px.jpg 600w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_14_400px.jpg 400w,"
                >
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide"> 
                <img class="lazyload bild" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_03_3000px.jpg 3000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_03_2000px.jpg 2000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_03_1000px.jpg 1000w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_03_600px.jpg 600w,
                links/Branding_Theater_Marie/THE_Branding_Theater_Marie_03_400px.jpg 400w,"
                >
            </div>

            
        </div>

        <!-- next / prev arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <!-- !next / prev arrows -->
        
        <!-- pagination dots -->
        <!-- <div class="swiper-pagination"></div> -->
        <!-- !pagination dots -->
    </div>
```

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
// Optional parameters
direction: 'horizontal',
spaceBetween: 20,
slidesPerView: "auto",
centeredSlides: true,
grabCursor: true,
loop: true,
mousewheel: false,
keyboard: {
enabled: true
},

```
        // Navigation arrows
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },

      });
```